# The collection of questions increases with 10 questions, every time I resolve the quiz

Tags: c#, collections

I am writing a C# program to display a test of questions.
The test has 10 questions.
But the program doesn't want to follow the same algorithm if I select a new quiz with the help of

```
   private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
```

The quiz doesn't stop after 10 questions.It goes on, it repeats the questions and at a certain number of questions it blocks.

I stepped through the code,and I saw:

- When I resolve the quiz for the first time:`questions.Count=10;`
- When I resolve it for the second time: `questions.Count=20;`
- when I resolve it for the third time: `questions.Count=30`;

Would you like to tell me how can I have `questions.Count=10` for every quiz, please ?

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    int nr;
    Collection<question> questions = new Collection<question>();

    public class question
    {
        public bool displayed = false;
        public string text;
    }


    //when I press a button from MenuStrip my quiz begin
    private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        nr = 1;
        button1.Enabled = true;//it's the next_question button

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("quiz.txt");
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {   
            question i = new question();
            questions.Add(i);
        }
        sr.Close();
        int x = r.Next(questions.Count);
        textBox1.Text = questionText;
        questions[x].displayed = true;
        current_question=x;
      }
}
```

I add that I tried to create

```
       Collection<question> questions = new Collection<question>()
```

for every quiz I resolve, putting this at the beginning of the

```
       private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

or at the end of my current quiz:

```
       if (nr >= questions.Count){ //here }
```

None of these changes prevent the collection to increase with 10 questions.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Add a Clear method call:

```
questions.Clear();
```

Like so:

```
private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   nr = 1;
    button1.Enabled = true;//it's the next_question button
    questions.Clear();

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("quiz.txt");
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {   
        question i = new question();
        questions.Add(i);
    }
    sr.Close();
    int x = r.Next(questions.Count);
    textBox1.Text = questionText;
    questions[x].displayed = true;
    current_question=x;

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
questions = new Collection<question>();
```

at the start of the `newToolStripMenuItem_Click` method or use `question.Clear();`

Do NOT include the type `Collection<question>` in front of it because then you are creating a new local variable.